# User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on starting in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, user-profile-service

User profile synchronization service was not working properly so I have stopped the service and try to restart but it stuck on starting.

What I have tried:

- Restart the UPS service thru PowerShell
- Forefront Identity Manager service and Forefront Identity Manager 
  Synchronization Service both services are up and running
- User is farm administrator and in local administrator group

Still, service is stuck on starting state.

Comment: Please, Make sure that after adding the farm account to start UPS in Local Admin Group, you have to restart the timer service, also check this URL https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/14/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting/

Comment: I have already tried all the steps showing in the portals, still no luck.

Comment: try this once https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108583/user-profile-synchronization-service-stuck-on-starting

Comment: how long you have waited to get it start?because it takes too much time to get started!