# GetUserProfileByName result Log ID:5566 for some users

Tags: infopath, error

In our envirenment we are using GetUserProfileByName to collect user data in infopath forms

Since couple of months there was one user who when connect recieved error ID:5566

> An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.
>
> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.
>
> Log ID:5566
>
> Correlation ID:e0bf3f9e-0ffc-202c-29fd-9214d8d65bdf

Since January I have 2 other user's with the same issue.
Does anyone can help me with proposal of the solution.

I searched since the beginning but now it becomes bigger problem.
Thank you,

Comment: Can you please tell us the error logged against correlation id

Comment: I tried to find it on my sharepoint server in event viewer and could not find this Log ID

Comment: You need to check uls logs.

Comment: I'm checking ULS logs right now thank you However I cannot scope log ID 5566.... I tried with corellation  ID. Also cannot find it. I checked if it's monitored and yes it is.

Comment: Try to reproduce the error and then try finding the latest correlation id

Comment: I am searching now events concerning Infopath there are some logs on my requests but nothing useful (I did reproduce the problem couple of times)

Comment: I found out after reproducing it on the sharepoint core server. I see one error which says that  "Internal web service routing is not enabled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was linked to : 
[User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on starting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108583/user-profile-synchronization-service-stuck-on-starting)

User profile synchronisation service was disabled.

I had an issue to enable it it was blocked on provisioning.
I had to stop the service by

`Stop-spserviceinstance <GUID>`

Log on as Farm administrator and start the service.

After Sync it's working perfectly.